# Specman macro to do set subtraction with int_range_list objects

Tags: specman

I work with a bunch of sets in order to generate constrained random traffic, but I want to be able to call a Specman macro that computes the complement of a set with syntax like:

```
COMPLEMENT begin 
   domain=[0..10,24..30],
   complementing_set=[2..3,27..30] 
end
```

and have it generate:

```
[0..1,4..10,24..26]
```

Every time I need the complement of a set I'm using fully populated lists (e.g. {0;1;2;3....} ) and then removing elements, instead of using Specman's built-in int_range_list object.  And I'm also doing a lot of these set calculations at run-time instead of compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
var domain: list of int = {0..10, 24..30}; 
var complementing_set: list of int = {2..3, 27..30};
var complement: list of int = domain.all(it in complementing set);
```

The `all` pseudo-method generates a sublist of the parent list of all the elements in the parent list for which the condition in the parentheses holds.

Comment: That's a really great way to do unions with a list of int!  My goal is to *not* use  list_of_int's, because it consumes too much memory.  We have 16+ nodes in our design and the nodes are of varying types.  I want to use int_range_list because Specman is quicker when testing if a val is in the set.

Comment: I also don't want to do a lot of computation dynamically.  I'm looking at tons of packet fields on the fly, and I want to speed up the testing of whether a certain integer lives within some set ( or union of different sets).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I don't think there is a solution, because Specman doesn't have a very good pre-processor.   I was mostly just testing to see if stackoverflow could help me generate answers tough, obscure-language questions.

Answer (score 2):

In the recent versions of Specman, you can use the pre-defined `set` type, that serves exactly this purpose. For example, you can do things like this:

```
var s1: set = [1..5, 10..15];
var s2: set = [4..13];
var s3: set = s1.intersect(s2);
```

and even like this:

```
x: int;
y: int;
........
var s1: set = [x..y];
var s2: set = [1..10];
var s3: set = s1.union(s2);
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

one more way may be to use uints, say you have a 500 possible values:

```
domain : uint(bits:500);
complement : uint(bits:500);
set : uint(bits:500) = domain & ~complement;
```

you can later extract the indices with

```
set_l : list of uint = set[.]].all_indices(it==1);
```

depending on your domain to possible values ratio this method may be quicker to calculate